# Cypress cy.origin is doesn't work when it link to LinkedIn

Tags: javascript, cypress, user-agent, cypress-origin

I was developing a feature that redirects users to profiles on various platforms.
And to test this, I wrote the following code using the newly released `cy.origin` yesterday.

```js
cy.origin('www.example.com', () => {
    cy.visit('/username')
})
```

However, github and twitter were successfully redirected, but linkedin was not the only one.

[image: error image]

I think the problem is caused by the user agent. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: It works ok for me.  `cy.origin('https://www.linkedin.com', () => { cy.visit('/login') })` - no errors.

Comment: @Fody It works to me too. but user's profile is not work,
try changing `cy.visit('/login')` to `cy.visit('/in/sunwoo0706')`

Comment: Yeah I did that too - got a bad status code but with `{failOnStatusCode: false}` I get redirected. Didn't get your error.

Comment: it works to me !!, But I don't think `{failOnStatusCode: false}` is a good way to test. If the URL is not valid and returns 404, the test will be passed.

Comment: You don't have a choice, unless you work at Linkedin and can change the server.

Comment: So, looks like it's nothing to do with `cy.origin()` - this would happen if you just did a simple `cy.visit()`

Comment: @user16695029 I understand that cypress needs to use `cy.origin()` to visit different origin. Is it different from what I know?

Answer (score 1):

For the record,

```js
cy.origin('https://www.linkedin.com', () => {
  cy.visit('/in/sunwoo0706', {failOnStatusCode: false})  // redirects to login page
})
```

Comment: If the URL is not valid and returns 404, the test will be passed.

Comment: That's true. Is the purpose of the test to validate the URL? If so, I recommend using `cy.request()` to test it rather than `cy.visit()`. There is a recipe somewhere for that.

Comment: I see. I'll keep that in mind. Thank you for your answer!